# How can I align a text after a few characters?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Please see the picture below. Having all text aligned with the line after the 'a.' below makes the document more structured, but how can I do this? It will probably be something very straightforward, sorry. Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JK7W.jpg)

Comment: Welcome, seems you ant an `enumerate` list, so load package `enumitem` and do `[label=alph*]` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want, with `ntheorem` and `enumitem`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{label=\alph*. wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, labelsep=0.33em, font=\bfseries, topsep=2pt, before= \leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}

\begin{exercise}
  \begin{questions}%
 \item \lipsum[4-5]
\end{questions}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a one-off "hanging indentation" effect that you're looking to achieve, a combination of `\hangindent=<length>` and `\hangafter=1` should let you achieve your objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Exercise 1.1}

\hangindent=\parindent\hangafter=1 a. \lipsum[2]

\noindent
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The enumerate from [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard)'s answer is perfect should you ever need to add more elements and just need to go through the letters alphabetically (a. , b. , c. , ...). However, if these get more complicated, you could also use the [description structure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#List_structures). This allows you to easily define longer keywords but keep the same indentation on consecutive lines / paragraphs. Here's a quick wiki example for the description (note that the [`blindtext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is just to generate text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [a.] \blindtext
\item [b.] \blindtext
\item [Something longer and quite different than a. and b.] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

By combining this with the `enumitem` package, you can align text either to the left or to the right. Here's a horrendous but obvious example by using the same descriptions here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[align=right, labelwidth=5cm]
\item [a.] \blindtext
\item [b.] \blindtext
\item [Something longer and quite different than a. and b.] \blindtext
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Output from first latex block]

---

[image]